# Libsvm includes training data in testing file

Tags: svm, libsvm

Currently I'm using libsvm (Java) for my one class classification problem. I scaled both of my training data and testing data by svm_scale, the problem is that somehow,libsvm includes both training data and testing data in the scaled testing data file. So e.g. my training data contains 10 samples, my testing data contains 5 samples, the result will be something like

```
Accuracy: xx.xx% (14/15) (classification)
```

What I am expected is

```
Accuracy: xx.xx% (4/5) (classification)
```

Should this be my fault or libsvm's ?

Thank you very much.

P/S The code:

```
    String[] parametersForTrainSVMScale = {"-l", "-1", "-u", "1", "-s", range, rawTrainFileName};
    writeFile(svm_scale.scale(parametersForTrainSVMScale), scaledTrainFileName);

    String[] parametersForTestSVMScale = {"-r", range, rawTestFileName};
    writeFile(svm_scale.scale(parametersForTestSVMScale), scaledTestFileName);

    String[] parametersForSVMTrain = {"-s", "2", "-t", "2", "-n", "0.1", "-c", String.valueOf(c), "-g", String.valueOf(g), "-b", "0", scaledTrainFileName, modeledFileName};
    svm_train.main(parametersForSVMTrain);

    String[] parametersForSVMPredict = {"-b", "0", scaledTestFileName, modeledFileName, testedFileName};
    svm_predict.main(parametersForSVMPredict);
```

Comment: is it possible for you to upload the code? Thanks

Comment: Sure, i added the code to the question